# Knockout and InitializeViewBag method (MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, knockout.js

Visual studio doesn't understand method InitializeViewBag("Simple list") from example below. 
How does it make? Does this method exist?

Why in this example, it is used : [Example](http://knockoutmvc.com/CartEditor)

**Model**

```
public class SimpleListModel
{
    public string ItemToAdd { get; set; }
    public List<string> Items { get; set; }

    public void AddItem()
    {
        Items.Add(ItemToAdd);
        ItemToAdd = "";
    }
}
```

**Razor**

```
@using PerpetuumSoft.Knockout
@model KnockoutMvcDemo.Models.SimpleListModel
@{
    var ko = Html.CreateKnockoutContext();
}
@using (ko.Html.Form("AddItem", "SimpleList", null, new { id = "myform" }))
{
    <span>New item:</span>
    @ko.Html.TextBox(m => m.ItemToAdd).ValueUpdate(KnockoutValueUpdateKind.AfterKeyDow n) 
    <button type="submit" @ko.Bind.Enable(m => m.ItemToAdd.Length >
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class SimpleListController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        InitializeViewBag("Simple list");
        var model = new SimpleListModel { Items = new List<string> { "Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma" } };
        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult AddItem(SimpleListModel model)
    {
        model.AddItem();
        return Json(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: What you mean "Visual studio doesn't understand method InitializeViewBag("Simple list")"? Do you get comilation erros? Maybe you don't add reference to required library?

Comment: error : InitializeViewBag does not exist

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/AndreyAkinshin/knockout-mvc/blob/master/KnockoutMvcDemo/Controllers/BaseController.cs) for BaseController in github, I can see that InitializeViewBag method is defined there. That's how SimpleListController has access to it. If you have that same exact implementation of BaseController and the method is still not recognised, I would think it's something annoying, like an extra bracket here or there, or a duplicate BaseController somewhere else.